# Splitting orderDetail into two tables for a database?

Tags: database, database-design, key, entity, composite

I will try my best to phrase this in a way that makes sense. I am working on a database project for my beginning database management course that uses a fictional scenario of a bookstore owner who wants me to create a database for them.

Essentially, the tables (or entities) that I have come up with are as follows:

```
Customer,
Product,
Order,
orderLine,
Book,
Author,
Publisher
```

To put it simply, I need configure this so that I can track both books and other nonbook items from sales. The issue that I am running into with this is that when I tried to just have one products table, I ran into the issue that books have a bunch of attributes that other items (such as bakery items). If I put books with other items, then there would be a whole lot of empty cells where there is no author/publisher/genre. From what my textbook has taught me so far, a composite table is needed for an orderDetail-type table, where the orderNumber and productNumber would combine. But here, I would need to somehow combine two seperate KEY attributes (for books and other items) into one order table, or some other method. This is especially confusing to me since some customers might buy a combination of books an other items in a single order, or they might only buy one type of thing. I was thinking that the ISBN would be an excellent identifier key for the Book table. What kind of configuration would I need to track orders like this?

Answer (score 1):

Add one more table , product-props and store attributes in that table. you can keep all products in one table i.e books and other items as well.  you can move author, publisher as props of this as well

Comment: Would that still allow me to run different queries about sales per month by author, publisher, etc?

Comment: Yes ,you can get results per author ,per time period as well.